# Creating Menus in adobe flex

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I am working on a game in flex, and I am trying to figure out how to create menus in the game. I am was thinking it would be easy just to add and remove a child for the menu, but then it would be a pain to make interactive. I figure there must be some way to do it, so I am asking here.

I am trying to do both a pop up menu and an always on screen menu, like a bottom menu bar, so if anyone has any ideas please let me know. I am completely new to flash and flex and don't really know where to start past making the actual game. Thanks

WWaldo

Comment: Why oh why are you creating a game in Flex?  Flex is a UI framework, not a game framework, unless the game is just full of UI elements...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terms of making a menu with different appearances based off of the state of something, check out the built in state management :

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf63611-7ffa.html

This lets you define what children appear in which state of the menu, then you just set the currentState : `currentState='soundMenu'`

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the Flex [MenuBar](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/MenuBar.html) class?

More [documentation on it here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=menucontrols_5.html).

If you need something spark related, check out the [ButtonBar](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSc2368ca491e3ff92-59bf082612135c9e688-8000.html) and see about extending that.

Beyond that, I'm unclear exactly what you want.  Adding and removing children to any given Flex UIComponent is pretty easy.  I don't know why that would make it hard for things to be interactive.